# Azure Data Factory Dynamic Content Filename Syntax

Tags: azure-data-factory

In a copy process going from one storage account to another I am trying to pick up the filenames in the sours and add the date to the filename in the destination so that each file copied is unique and no files are overwritten in the destination but I can't seem to get the syntax for filenames right. Welcome any suggestions on where are good examples to learn from.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

1. Parameterize the source file name in the source dataset and get the files list using the `Get Metadata` activity from the source folder.

[image]

**Get Metadata output:**

[image]

2. Pass the Get Metadata output child items to `ForEach` activity.

`@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`

[image]

3. Inside ForEach activity, add copy data activity to copy files from source to sink.
4. In `Copy` activity **source**, pass the current item as source file name dataset parameter.

[image]

5. Parameterize sink file name in sink dataset. In Copy activity **sink**, pass the expression to include date value in the file name.

**Sink dataset:**

[image]

**Copy activity sink:**

`@concat(replace(item().name,'.csv',''),'_',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyyMMdd HHmmss'),'.csv')`

[image]

6. **Output:**

[image]