# How can I copy files from an input container to an output container using below logic with Azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How can I copy files from an input container to an output container in Azure blob storage, and sort them into three different folders based on their file size, with files less than 1KB going to the 1KB folder, files between 1KB to 2KB going to the 2KB folder, and files larger than 2KB going to the more than 2KB_More folder?

Any one can help on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to **@Nandan**'s answer, The 4th step in the above process can be done like below.

After getting file size from second Get meta data activity, first convert the bytes to KB with the below expression.

```
@string(div(activity('Get Metadata2').output.size,1024))
```

[image]

Then use **if expression** in another variable set the folder names like below.

```
@if(equals(int(variables('size')),0),'1KB',if(equals(int(variables('size')),1),'2KB','2KB_more'))
```

[image]

Use this name in the sink dataset foldername.
**My Result:**

[image]

**NOTE:** If you are copying different types of files, it's better to use a binary datasets for this.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below logical flow :

1. use get meta data activity to get child items list within the input container
2. use for each activity with child items list as input
3. within for each, use get meta data activity to get file size
4. use set variable activity to set the destination path based on file size
5. use copy activity with dynamic sink
   sample for dynamic : [Azure Data Factory Dynamic Content Filename Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71042704/azure-data-factory-dynamic-content-filename-syntax)

Comment: I am getting file size as bytes .is there any size property convert bytes to kb .

Comment: Hey, you can divide by 1000 to convert it in KB